# track progress of moving to recycle bin on windows

Tags: c++, winapi

I was planning to use `IFileOperation::DeleteItems(items)` and `IFileOperationProgressSink::UpdateProgress(workTotal, workSoFar)` to track the progress of moving files and folders to recycle bin. But this only works well when I call it on a list of files to be deleted/move to recycle bin. Then `UpdateProgress()` is called correctly after each file, returning gradually increasing number of deleted items. But when I try to delete one large folder containing multiple nested subfolders and thousand of files, `UpdateProgress()` keeps returning 0 (as the number of files done) and then suddenly it returns for example 8000 (like 8000 files in the large folder were deleted). There is no gradual progress, it just jumps from 0% to 100 %. Is this the normal behavior? Or am I doing something wrong. I would like to show the code but even the relevant snippet is terribly long.

Comment: Just describing the code isn't enough, you really need to try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: The code is really long (because there are lots of abstract methods one must implement for the interfaces). I was just curious whether anybody knows how `IFileOperationProgressSink::UpdateProgress()` behaves when used for folders. If jumping from 0 to 100 % is the normal behaviour then I am not able to work around this and I must try to find another solution.

Comment: I imagine this is normal behaviour: Progress might be calculated on removing items from the list, but as this one only contains one item (the folder), update occurs just once when done (meaning in consequence that `DeleteItems` doesn't pre-scan to know how many individual files there are...).

Comment: If 8000 files are evenly distributed to two folders, will they be from 0% - 50% - 100%?

Comment: @Drake Wu Yes - 0%-50%-100%.

Answer (score 1):

I simply modified the sample on [Windows-classic-samples](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appplatform/FileOperationProgressSink) and tried at least 8,000 files in the same subfile. It works for the `UpdateProgress` method, the process first discover all the items, then delete it in process.

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is the [sample](https://github.com/BESTRIVENinCN/FileOperationProgressSink) I used.

Comment: I am afraid I found that this code unfortunately does not move items to trash but it deletes them. If I add any of these `FOF_ALLOWUNDO`, `FOFX_ADDUNDORECORD` or `FOFX_RECYCLEONDELETE` into `SetOperationFlags()`, then it starts behaving as I described in my original post.