# PySide6: How to update a progress bar when moving directory to trash recursively?

Tags: qt, pyside, pyside6, qt6

I want to move a non-empty directory to trash. `QFile.moveToTrash()` does this if passed a directory path, but it moves the whole directory in one go so I can't get a progress bar with it.
I tried:

```py
dir_ = QDir(dir_path)
for idx, file in enumerate(dir_.entryList(QDir.Filter.Files | QDir.Filter.NoDotAndDotDot)):
  file_path = dir_.fileName(file)
  progress.setLabelText(file_path)
  QFile.moveToTrash(file_path)
  progress.setValue(idx)
```

but it moves the files to the root trash directory:

```
Trash
|
|ーfile1
|ーfile2
|ーfile3
...
```

and I want it moved within a subdirectory in the trash directory:

```
Trash
|
|ーdirectory
      |
      |ーfile1
      |ーfile2
      |ーfile3
```

I could do some workarounds and move the directory and its files however I see fit, i.e. implementing my own `move_to_trash` function, but moving to trash is a pretty complicated thing to do it would seem. Is there a Qt way I can show a progress bar while moving a non-empty directory to trash?

Comment: No. That's a higher level API through the OS, Qt can have absolutely ***no*** means of knowing the progress of the deletion. Assuming that the OS *does* provide such an api, you have to look for that support on Python, otherwise set the maximum to `0`, as the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html#details): "If minimum and maximum both are set to 0, the bar shows a busy indicator instead of a percentage of steps. This is useful, for example, when using QNetworkAccessManager to download items when they are unable to determine the size of the item being downloaded.".

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @musicamante . My goal with the progress bar was more so to display the files being deleted one after another, kind of like how file explorers do it. I'll look into if there's an API for this.

Comment: @London You have not specified which OS are you targeting and I bet that the system API will be very different for each OS. If you are on Windows however, you may take a look at my older question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57461683/track-progress-of-moving-to-recycle-bin-on-windows which unfortunately does not have much of a solution. But it may at least point you to some areas in windows API where you might start digging for more knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager . I'm not targeting a specific OS, I want my program to work the same on all OSs. Also, thank you for the link, I was troubled by what to do on Windows; for Linux I can use the free desktop specifications to get the trash directory, on OSX it's in the user home, but Windows was a mystery.

Comment: @London Just one more piece of advice which is relevant for Windows only. Superficially, this task may seem simple: you just remove individually file by file and track the progress of how many files are done. But this will not result in expected outcome on Windows. Because if you send a whole folder, then sending file by file will result in individual files being in the trash instead of the complete folder. So if the user decides he wants to move the whole folder out of the trash, he will not be able to do this. So it is definitely not easy, if you manage to find a solution, I am all ears.

Comment: @London Maybe my previous comment is a bit confusing, I ran out of characters for comment. If you move to trash file by file from a folder, then you can track the progress, but the user will not be able to restore the whole folder back if he wants. So you need to move to trash the whole folder, not file by file. But in that case the progress is hard to track. So that is the problem.

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager ,  I understood what you were trying to say. That is a problem indeed; with Unix based OSs I can create the to-be-deleted directory in the designated `.Trash` directory and move the files there, but that doesn't seem possible with Windows; at least not as far as I know. I might try to solve it sometime in the future, but right now I'm content with only displaying the name of the directory being moved to trash (as opposed to singular file names).